# Company printing stuff to console in ESS

Tags: company-mode, ess

I am using company with ESS, and in some contexts, company will print weird documentation messages to the console:

```
(list "" '(("..." . "")) '("recursive" "use.names" "..." "x" "replace" "drop_null" "con"))
```

This seems to happen when the cursors is inside certain functions like `c`.
Is there any way to deactivate this behavior?

Edit:

For now, a workaround is to uninstall eldoc and eldoc-stan. This doesn't seem optimal, though...

Comment: Looks like a bug. Perhaps report it to ESS?

Comment: I found [this on github](https://github.com/emacs-ess/ESS/issues/794) but haven't been able to put into a solution.

Comment: a workaround is to get the latest ESS from github. So there is some incompatibility between the stable version and emacs 28.